# C++ Read Access Violation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

The title says it all. I am having trouble figuring out what that error could mean, as I've never heard of it prior to now.

```
string Cracker_Functions::Loop(string Password, char fullset[]) {
    int x = 0;
    char word[32] = "";
    int Passwordlen = Password.length();

    for (int a = 0; a < Passwordlen; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < 92; b++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 92; c++) {
                word[b] = fullset[c];

                if (word == Password) {
                    return word;
                }
            }

            word[b] = fullset[a]; 
            continue;
        }

        word[a] = fullset[x];
        x += 1;
    }

    return "";
}
```

The program throws an exception at:

```
word[a] = fullset[x];
```

Notes on the function:
All necessary files are included.
The function is predefined in another file.
The number 32 is the maximum size of password the computer will try to guess.
The number 92 is the total amount of characters that the computer can cycle through.
fullset is all the characters in one list.
word represents what the program is currently cycling through. For example the current combination of characters is "h#(u?"
x is the counter for when the first loop is done with the other 2, and needs to reassign a new letter to begin again with.

Comment: You're using C++ so please, **please**, use `std::string` whenever possible. `char[32]` can only hold 31 characters, so you're setting yourself up for failure if you overflow that buffer. You should also get in the habit of declaring arguments like `const string&` as that's cheaper and safer than passing in by value.

Comment: @tadman Minor nitpick, it'll hold 32 characters, but the last one is expected to be the null terminator. So in effect the password length should be at most 31. That being said, I concur on the "use `std::string`" part.

Comment: This function could be boiled down to `return ""` anyway. If you're having trouble with C++, which is understandable as it's a very difficult language to master, you might want to prototype this in something like Ruby or Python first where you don't have to worry about a lot of the technical details C++ forces you to deal with.

Comment: @Borgleader 31 "useful" characters, then. True, you can hold 32 if you use fixed-length strings, but that's not the case here, not that I can actually tell what's going on in this code because it looks like a pastiche of a bunch of different bits of code. The intent is far from clear, so this is a case where comments are not optional. What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: This:  char word[32] = "";   doesn't do what you think it does. Is your password longer than 32 characters? If so 'word[a]' will access memory after the end of the array.

Comment: @tadman The intent of the program is to use brute force to figure out someone's password. but that is just the function that is giving the problem, the actual cracker. also, the word array is to hold the current set of characters.

Comment: This naïve approach will not work, the search space is too large.